# Show that $\int_0^e \ln(1-\ln(x))dx=-e\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Wolfram Alpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bln%5C%2840%291-lnx%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ce%7D%5D) $\int_0^e \ln(1-\ln(x))dx=-e\gamma$ which I thought was really interesting. I want to understand how to solve this integral. Here is my attempt:

$$\int_0^e \ln(1-\ln(x))dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0 \ln(1-u)xdu$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0 \ln(1-u)e^udu$$
$$=\ln(1-u)e^u\bigg|^0_{-\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{1-u}e^udu$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^u}{1-u}du$$

I feel like I am so close here but I can't figure out how to continue.

Comment: Perform the substitution $t=1-u$, then you end up with [$E_1$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $t=1-\ln x$. Then, $ dx = e^{1-t}dt$ and
\begin{align}\int_0^e \ln(1-\ln x)dx
=e \int^\infty_0\ln t \ e^{-t}dt=-e\gamma
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from where I previously left off based off of Gary's suggestion.

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^u}{1-u}du$$
$$=-\int_{\infty}^1\frac{e^{1-t}}{t}dt$$
$$=e\int^{\infty}_1\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$
$$=eE_1(1)$$
$$=-e\gamma$$